# Will context be used as default in the entire sql transaction?

Tags: go

I was wondering if you start a transaction with a context if the whole transaction will "listen" to that context here?

```
tx, _ := db.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelSerializable})
stmt, _ := tx.Prepare("SELECT id, timeout, lang FROM client WHERE id=?")
```

Or do you explicitly apply the context to each query?

```
tx, _ := db.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelSerializable})
stmt, _ := tx.PrepareContext(ctx, "SELECT id, timeout, lang FROM client WHERE id=?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `Prepare`, and other contextless methods, use [context.Background](https://pkg.go.dev/context@go1.21.3#Background).

From the [Tx.Prepare docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Tx.Prepare)...

> Prepare uses context.Background internally; to specify the context, use PrepareContext.

Looking at [the source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=2359), it's just a simple wrapper.

```
func (tx *Tx) Prepare(query string) (*Stmt, error) {
    return tx.PrepareContext(context.Background(), query)
}
```

While Tx has does store the Context from `db.BeginTx`, that is only used for the transaction. It does not use that for queries because [sharing Contexts leads to confusion and restrictions](https://docs.studygolang.com/blog/context-and-structs).

Comment: "you're not supposed to store Contexts in structs" - `db.Tx` does [store the context](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=2166). As per [the `BeginTx` docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Conn.BeginTx) "The provided context is used until the transaction is committed or rolled back. If the context is canceled, the sql package will roll back the transaction".

Comment: @Brits db predates Contexts. They had to be added to an existing library and maintain backwards compatibility. Because it wasn't designed with contexts in mind, sometimes that means putting it in the struct. See [Exception to the rule: preserving backwards compatibility](https://docs.studygolang.com/blog/context-and-structs#TOC_4.). "Don't store contexts in structs" is not a hard and fast rule, as the article explains, [it's a rule of thumb to avoid confusion](https://docs.studygolang.com/blog/context-and-structs#TOC_3.). I'm sure there are other exceptions.

Comment: @Brits I think it's better to say that storing contexts in structs, vs passing them around, invites implicit sharing of Contexts which leads to confusion and restrictions. The context stored by db.Tx is only for the transaction. This allows the user to know for sure what a Context is effects, they don't want to go to cancel a query and then find they've cancelled the whole transaction. I don't know if I 100% agree with this, but I don't have a lot of experience with contexts, and that's the official Go line.

Comment: Sorry - my point (probably badly made) was that the context passed to `BeginTx` has an impact on the overall transaction. If the context has been cancelled before `Prepare` is called then `Prepare` will fail (transaction already rolled back); if the context is cancelled before `Commit` then that will fail. So while `Prepare` itself uses `context.Background()` the `BeginTx` `ctx` still has an impact (meaning it makes sense to use `PrepareContext`).